# После прохода switch, console.log выдаёт undefined. Что не так?

Tags: javascript

```
const getPriceOfSelect = () => {

    switch (valueOfSelect) {
        case 10:
            priceOfMovie = 10;
            return priceOfMovie;
            break;
        case 12:
            priceOfMovie = 12;
            return priceOfMovie;
            break;
        case 8:
            priceOfMovie = 8;
            return priceOfMovie;
            break;
        case 9:
            priceOfMovie = 9;
            return priceOfMovie;
            break;
        default:
            return alert( "Нет таких значений" );
    }
} 

const changeStyleOfPlace = (getElementFromArray, priceOfMovie) => {

    if (getElementFromArray.currentTarget.className == "row__place") {
        getElementFromArray.currentTarget.className = "row__selected";
        document.querySelector(".text__total").innerHTML += priceOfMovie;
    }
    else {
        getElementFromArray.currentTarget.className = "row__place";
    }
}
```

---

```
document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener('change', function() {
  let valueOfSelect = Number(this.value);
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let valueOfSelect = Number(document.querySelector(".select").value);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никакого "прохода switch" в коде нет, так как `getPriceOfSelect` не вызывается.

---

Формальный параметр `priceOfMovie` функции `changeStyleOfPlace` не имеет отношения к внешней переменной `priceOfMovie`, если только эта переменная не используется в качестве второго параметра в вызове `changeStyleOfPlace`.

---

Локальная переменная `valueOfSelect` не видна снаружи тех функций, где она объявлена. Таким образом, значение `valueOfSelect` в `switch (valueOfSelect) {` не определено.

```
let valueOfSelect;

document.querySelector(".select").addEventListener('change', function() {
  valueOfSelect = Number(this.value);
});
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  valueOfSelect = Number(document.querySelector(".select").value);
});
```